# Presenting flow charts diagrams in a mobile app

Tags: interaction-design, usability, scrolling

I am working on an app which junior doctors will use for clinical pathways, these clinical pathways are currently presented as flow chart diagrams which I'm not too keen on. I think there's a better way to present them so from a usability perspective how else do you think I can present these flow chart diagrams in my app so they are easy to see and navigate.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are flowcharts inherently not usable? In much of medical literature, clinical pathways are already presented in flowchart format. Representing it as such in a decision support system would seem at first glance intuitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present in steps, based on the flow - like a decision tree. For example:

**Does the patient have xxx?**

**-Yes-   -No-**

Where Yes and No would take you to subsequent steps.

If you follow this pattern (speaking from experience) - please consider the following things:

- sometime expert users will just need reminders, and will find navigating an entire flow tedious - provide a way for them to see the entire chart
- flows will never cover every case - provide a way out, or an esclation, if the user's option is not available
- watch out for 'loops' - if a user follows the same 2 steps in the same order, twice in any one flow then you the user is stuck.  Again, provide a way out.

IMO - the trickiest thing is not the UI, it is writing the flows and testing them - they can get very complex.  Make sure to put significant usability test time into your authoring tool as well as your front end.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, really appreciate it.